# DB2 CLOB size in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

A json is assigned to result which is greater than 50MB in a DB2 stored procedure. But the size of the result which is inserted or returned is only approx. 1MB. Should I have to define the size of the CLOB?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALCULATE_CLOB
(
  OUT result CLOB
)
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SQL2433453455
BEGIN
        DECLARE result CLOB;
        SET result = ... json
        
        INSERT INTO DATA
        VALUES(result);
        return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

The default length of a CLOB in Db2 is 1M (1 megabyte) for z/os, luw, and i-series. So CLOB is the same as CLOB(1M).

When you want a larger clob, you must specify the size when you declare a variable, or when you specify a parameter to a routine. For example, CLOB(50M), or CLOB(1G) etc. The maximum length is 2G.

This is per the Db2 documentation, see the `create table` statement for your Db2-server platform and version.

Always specify your Db2-server platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows/cloud) and Db2-server version when asking for help, because the answer can depend on these facts.

As you appear to be learning how to code stored procedures, you may benefit from studying the examples provided by IBM for SQL PL, which are available in various places. For example, online in the Db2 Knowledge Centre for your version of db2-server, and on [github](https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/tree/master/sqlpl), and also in the `samples` subdirectory tree of your Db2-LUW server installation (if installed). Spending time on such examples will help you because you will be able to answer simple questions without waiting for answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: It is LUW. But when I want to return the result, means the CLOB I will get only 1MB on client side, although it should be 50MB. So how I can achieve that exactly the real size of the CLOB is returned?

Comment: Yes,  you have to define an appropriate / sufficient size of the variable, if its default size is not suitable for your goal. Default size for each data type is described at the [Compound SQL (compiled) statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-compound-sql-compiled) link (see the `built-in-type` topic). If you specify just `CLOB` it means `CLOB (1M)` according to the description as it has been mentioned already. So, you need, say, `CLOB (100M)`.

Comment: BTW, don't give the same name to a local variable and a parameter unless you really know the identifier resulution rules in Db2 routines. The RETURN statement is not for an output parameter assignment, and it must have an int argument. Use the SET statement for such an assignment.

Comment: What do you mean with int argument?

Comment: INTEGER. [RETURN statement in SQL procedures](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=procedures-return-statement-in-sql).

Comment: Ok now I define the CLOB size to 50MB. But on application side I always get 2MB. Maybe it is limited by Hibernate?

Comment: @Db2fan, refer to the Hibernate documentation for details of specifying the length (for example, via annotation) in the mapping file or similar.

Comment: @DB2fan Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/zOJdS-wt) example confirming, that it's not a Db2 problem.